# Xcode compiles in Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can I force Xcode to compile everything in a specific directory instead of:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myproject-bdbyavaafjqvoghfedbmgxuxzvde/......
```

I'm compiling for bamboo and I would like to have full control where the compilation outputs and temps are stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can change in Xcode->Preferences->Locations: See attach image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are building from the command line using `xcodebuild` you can set the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` environment variable. `xcodebuild` also allows you to set these variables as part of your build command.

eg.

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -sdk iphoneos7.0 CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='/wherever/you/want'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XCode Plugin for Bamboo, then you can specify it under "Custom Parameters" (all the way to the bottom, see screenshot below)

[image: Xcode plugin for Bamboo]